# HTML Multiple Picture Alignment

Tags: html, css

I have some pictures I want to be displayed on a webpage. I would like them to be paired with some text centered above them. I have all of the content in a section centered with a max width of 640px. What I want is for these pictures (and their paired text) to sit next to each other, unless the window is shrunk to smaller than their width.

Max Width (640px +):

```
           Pikachu                        Squirtle

    IMAGE ONE GOES HERE ==============IMAGE TWO GOES HERE

          Charmander                      Bulbasaur

   IMAGE THREE GOES HERE=============IMAGE FOUR GOES HERE
```

Or if shrunk (less than two image widths):

```
           Pikachu

      IMAGE GOES HERE

           Squirtle

      IMAGE GOES HERE

          Charmander

      IMAGE GOES HERE

          Bulbasaur

      IMAGE GOES HERE
```

Edit:
I am new to html / css. I would like not to post my code on the site, so I apologize for my lack of it.

I just simply want the pictures to stay the same size. Just sit side by side when the width can support it. But I have a max width of 640px.

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Post code to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width:100%; clear:both; max-width:650px;">
<div style="float:left; width:45%;">
Pikachu<br>
<img src="pikachu.png">
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:45%;">
Squirtle<br>
<img src="squirtle.png">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the squirtle <div style="float:right;..." and it worked great. Thank you. Do you know how to center the Pikachu and Squirtle over the pictures? I haven't tried anything just yet though.

Comment: You could either add text-align:center to the divs which would center the text as well. Or you could add <center><img src="pikachu.png"></center> and I think you could do <img src="pickachu.png" align="middle">

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/Le495/

it's not very clear without your own code but you could use my example.

```
@media all and (max-width:650px) {
    .imagebox {width:100%}
}
}
```

this approach:

> the window is shrunk to smaller than their width.

doesn't really make sense in a responsive environment. if you want your image optimized for all widths, check this out: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/12/picturefill-2-0-responsive-images-and-the-perfect-polyfill/

Comment: This is very helpful! The comment "the window is shrunk to smaller than their width" wasn't worded well. I meant if the page isn't as wide as their combined width. I do not need to resize the images if the person is looking at the images with something really small. They can scroll left and right. I just didn't like my current setup with them vertically aligned even though they could easily fit side by side.